# AttributeError: module 'picamera' has no attribute 'picamera'

Tags: python, camera

```
import picamera
import time

camera= picamera.picamera()
camera.capture("example.jpg")
```

this is legitimately all the coding ive done for this project and its already not working. i use Thonny python on my raspberry pi 4

Comment: Rename your ~/picamera.py file to ANY OTHER name.

Comment: Hello there, next time, please post the EXACT stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Did you call your file `picamera.py`? If so, the file will try to import itself.

Rename it, and make sure there's no `picamera.py` or `picamera.pyc`.

Answer (score 2):

Casing is important:

```
import picamera
import time

camera= picamera.PiCamera()
camera.capture("example.jpg")
```

[image: Example using your code, then mine.]

*Should* solve your problem :)